# Macros that generate code from a for-loop

Tags: hy

This example is a little contrived. The goal is to create a macro that loops over some values and programmatically generates some code.

A common pattern in Python is to initialize the properties of an object at calling time as follows:

```
(defclass hair [foo bar]
  (defn __init__ [self]
    (setv self.foo foo)
    (setv self.bar bar)))
```

This correctly translates with `hy2py` to

```
class hair(foo, bar):

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        return None
```

I know there are Python approaches to this problem including attr.ib and dataclasses. But as a simplified learning exercise I wanted to approach this with a macro.

This is my non-working example:

```
(defmacro self-set [&rest args]
  (for [[name val] args]
    `(setv (. self (read-str ~name)) ~val)))

(defn fur [foo bar]
  (defn __init__ [self]
    (self-set [["foo" foo] ["bar" bar]])))
```

But this doesn't expand to the original pattern. `hy2py` shows:

```
from hy.core.language import name
from hy import HyExpression, HySymbol
import hy


def _hy_anon_var_1(hyx_XampersandXname, *args):
    for [name, val] in args:
        HyExpression([] + [HySymbol('setv')] + [HyExpression([] + [HySymbol
            ('.')] + [HySymbol('self')] + [HyExpression([] + [HySymbol(
            'read-str')] + [name])])] + [val])


hy.macros.macro('self-set')(_hy_anon_var_1)


def fur(foo, bar):

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        return None
```

Wbat am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` forms always return `None`. So, your loop is constructing the `(setv ...)` forms you request and then throwing them away. Instead, try `lfor`, which returns a list of results, or `gfor`, which returns a generator. Note also in the below example that I use `do` to group the generated forms together, and I've moved a `~` so that the `read-str` happens at compile-time, as it must in order for `.` to work.

```
(defmacro self-set [&rest args]
  `(do ~@(gfor
    [name val] args
    `(setv (. self ~(read-str name)) ~val))))

(defclass hair []
  (defn __init__ [self]
    (self-set ["foo" 1] ["bar" 2])))

(setv h (hair))
(print h.bar)   ; 2
```